# paypal api v2 - monthly subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to add monthly subscription to my website. However, the samples I found online now are all from version 1 and using the SDK. I read the document that paypal now have version 2 for their API but I just could not find any samples of codes for php on this new version

I would really appreciate if some one can help provide some links or guides that I can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

The current, latest version of the Subscription sAPI uses `v1` endpoints.

Creating a plan has a guide here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#3-create-a-plan

There are no PHP-specific samples, since there is no SDK for it. You must integrate using direct HTTPS calls. There are various ways to do an HTTPS call in PHP, including its own implementation of `curl`